# Query error when using single quotes around a number

Tags: syntax-error, mariadb

Query in **mariadb returns error results**.
To reproduce the problem:

### Create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  ID int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  test_field double(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### Insert some values:

```
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('1', '1.12');

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('2', '1.13');

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('3', '1.14');

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('4', '1.15');

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('5', '2.24');
```

### Run this query:

```
SELECT test_field FROM test_table WHERE test_field = '1.14'
```

The Maria db returns **nothing**.

If I use `'1.13'` instead of `'1.14'`, mariadb returns correctly one record.

It is understood that I should not use single quotes around the value but I would expect that the result would be correct, since the single quotes are not forbitten. It seems as a the type casting problem which I believe it has to addressed.

Comment: I think that the error it's the Auto-Increment, I mean you putted an auto-increment but you in the insert put the ID Value again... If you put an AUTO-INCREMENT you can't give the value to this field

Comment: Yes, it's probably a casting problem.  The fix is simple: don't insert strings into number columns.

Comment: @R.García I'm not sure that's true, but I'll agree that the OP shouldn't be manually assigning values to an auto increment column.

Comment: @R.García - You _can_ specify the auto_inc column.  But it is rarely advisable.  (In this example case, it is good, just to make sure everyone gets the same values.)

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use `(m,n)` on `DOUBLE` or `FLOAT`.  It causes an extra rounding.

Because `DOUBLE` and `FLOAT` are not exact decimal numbers it is folly to compare a `DOUBLE` to a `DECIMAL`.

`1.14` is converted to binary.  But when converted back to decimal you get something close to `1.1400000000000001`.

Bottom line:  Don't use `=` for testing `DOUBLE` or `FLOAT` values.  And don't use `(m,n)` with them.